# Type mismatch while splitting the values in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a Multivalue field which stores a value in 0th index. I'm trying to split the values using comma separator but it's throwing an error as type mismatch while I split the values. All the variables is declared as Variant datatype but still it throws the "Type Mismatch" error.
Thanks in advance.

```
    If Trim(doc.GetItemValue("fldPartNo_2")(0)) <> "" Then
        arrPartNo = ArrayAppend(doc.GetItemValue("fldPartNo_1"), doc.GetItemValue("fldPartNo_2"))
    Else
        arrPartNo = doc.GetItemValue("fldPartNo_1")
    End If
    
    arrRecdQty = doc.GetItemValue("fldRecdQty")
    arrUM = doc.GetItemValue("fldUM")
    arr=Split(arrUM,",")
    Dim n As Integer
    n=0
Do Until arr=""
    n=n+1
Loop
        sno = sno+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= doc.Universalid
        j=j+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value=sno
        j=j+1
        'MsgBox(CStr(arrUM(0)))
        For l=0 To n
            worksheet.cells(i,j).value= arrPartNo(l)
            j=j+1
            worksheet.cells(i,j).value= arrUM(l)
            j=j+1
            worksheet.cells(i,j).value= arrRecdQty(l)
            j=j+1
            worksheet.cells(i,j).value= doc.Getitemvalue("fldReject_"+CStr(l+1))
            j=j+1
    
            If IsNumeric(Trim(arrRecdQty(l))) Then
                If IsNumeric(Trim(doc.GetItemValue("fldReject_" + CStr(l + 1))(0))) Then
                    
                    worksheet.cells(i,j).value= arrRecdQty(l) - doc.GetItemValue("fldReject_" + CStr(l + 1))(0)
                j=j+1
                    
                    Else
                worksheet.cells(i,j).value= arrRecdQty(l)
                j=j+1
                    
            End If
            Else
                worksheet.cells(i,j).value= ""
                j=j+1
            End If
    Next
        
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= doc.GetItemValue("fldRemarks_" + CStr(l + 1))(0)
        j=j+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= "N_MRN"
        j=j+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= ""
        j=j+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= ""
        j=j+1
        worksheet.cells(i,j).value= "True"
        j=j+1
        Set doc = vw.Getnextdocument(doc)
        j = j + 1   
        sno=0   
        i = i + 1
        j = 1   
    Wend
```

Comment: Is fldUM Multivalue or not? If it IS multivalue then you don't need to split... If it is multi value but the FIRST value contains commas, then it would be `arr=Split(arrUM(0),",")`

Answer (score 4):

Get element 0 from arrUM first and then split the value by ","

```
arr=Split(arrUM(0),",")
```

Comment: really your comment is appreciable. I'm still facing type mismatch error

Comment: Are you sure it is this line of code that throws the error? Are you sure field "fldUM" is of type text and is multivalue? And, please delete the `Do Until ... Loop` lines as they will cause an infinitive loop.